# Spring Neo4j relationship infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm having an issue with Spring's @Fetch annotation. My model is very similar to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166845/naming-convention-for-bidirectional-relationships-in-neo4j-using-spring-data), and the example given works perfectly. Here's what my model looks like:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person {   
   @Indexed
   private String name;

   @Fetch
   @RelatedTo(type="OWNS", direction=Direction.OUTGOING) //or no direction, same thing
   private Set<Car> cars;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Car {   
   @Indexed
   private String description;

   @RelatedTo(type="OWNS", direction=Direction.INCOMING)
   private Person person;
}
```

The only difference between what is presented in the previous question and my model is that `@Fetch` annotation. If you want Spring to fetch the contents of this field when using Repositories, you have to use this. Unfortunately, this causes String to go into a loop, creating new instances of the same two objects over and over until it blows the heap. I can't seem to get around this, no matter what I do I either get stuck in a loop, or I don't get anything out of the Repository.

There is virtually no mention of this anywhere online. I'm thinking I'm googling the wrong thing, because this seems like a really common use case. IS there a workaround to this?

**EDIT:**

Possibly relevant: I am using a standalone Neo4j server, so SDN is operating over HTTP. I've noticed a few other weird, unmentioned behaviors as I've been developing in addition to this one. I'm starting to think that SDN's HTTP support is the culprit, and that having a standalone Neo4j server is somehow a weird thing. Almost every example/tutorial in existence for using Spring with Neo4j uses the embedded server.

Comment: This could be a limitation of SDN simple mapping, you could try advanced mapping, it's more flexible and you don't need to declare fetch strategies at all. More on this at [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference_mapping).

Comment: Perhaps you can create a small failing unit-test and project that you can share? Usually it only blows up if you use @Fetch on both sides so that you'll end in a loop. Please also put your data generation and loading code in that project.

Comment: I'll try and get something together for you. Right now, I'm just injecting the references in the service layer manually. If you don't include the `@Fetch` annotation, you still get the GraphID field filled in and you can resolve the full object pretty easily.